# Nested subspace and the fundamental group.

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Let $X$ be a topological space, and for each positive integer $n$ let $X_n$ be an arcwise- connected subspace containing the base point $x_0\in X$. Assume that the subspaces $X_n$ are nested, i.e., $X_n\subset X_{n+1}$ for all $n$, that 
>   $$X=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty X_{n}$$
>   and that for any compact subset $A$ of $X$ there exist an integer $n$ such that $A\subset X_n$. Let $i_n:\pi(X_n)\rightarrow\pi(X)$  and $j_{mn}:\pi(X_m)\rightarrow\pi(X_n)$, $m<n$, denote homomorphism induced by inclusion maps. 
>   Prove the following:
>   a) For any $\alpha\in \pi(X)$ there exist an integer $n$ and an element $\alpha'\in\pi(X_n)$ such that $i_n(\alpha')=\alpha$.
>   b) If $\beta\in\pi(X_n)$ and $i_m(\beta)=1$ then there exist an integer $n\geq m$ such that $j_{mn}(\beta)=1$.

I would like a hint to solve this exercise, in particular, how i should used the hypothesis about the compact sets?

Thanks!

Comment: The reason for the condition on the compact sets is that you can use the fact that the image of a compact set under a continuous map is compact. In particular if $\gamma\colon I\to X$ is a loop, then $\gamma(I)$ is a compact subset of $X$ and so there exists an $n$ such that $\gamma(I)\subset X_n$, hence if we define $\gamma'\colon I\to X_n$ by $\gamma'(t)=\gamma(t)$ then it is a well defined loop and so belongs to a homotopy class which is an element of $\pi_1(X_n)$.